# Changing between three languages and more in windows 10 conviniently

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, language

I'm using Windows 10 and I find myself confused every time I change between languages that have similar letters. Back then, when I had only two languages installed, switching languages via 'alt + shift' was fine - I were sure that I change to the right language, but now I found myself typing or don't understand why a shortcut isn't working and after several minutes I find that the current language was German and wasn't English. What I'm looking for is a way to see a clear notification, which occurs each time I switch languages, that shows the current language and fade away. Or shortcut which opens a box which I can choose the language I desire, and knowing for sure that I'm on the right language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this shortcut :  <kbd>Win</kbd>  +  <kbd>space</kbd> you can see it changing from the list

Comment: Thanks @Srinivas V!

Comment: @KaliTheGreat you can approve this answer. It will be helpful for you and others

Comment: After 7 minutes I can and will accept :) thanks again!

Comment: Recently (Windows 10.1909), it seems that the list also began showing up if you repeatedly press Shift while still holding Alt.